# CakePHP, images wont display in view

Tags: image, cakephp

I cannot, for the life of me, get my images to show up in my view.  I'm trying to display the thumbnails I createed, but I'm having no luck.  I just get broken images with everything I try.  I am currently using the image helper to display my images, but I still get broken images.

My Directory Structure is like so

webroot > img > project_images > thumbs

When my view renders `echo $this->Html->image('project_images/thumbs/' . $imageName);` the image tag looks like this

```
<img alt="" src="/img/project_images/thumbs/wordherd-1_thumb.jpg">
```

which looks right to me...but its not even rendering anything.  When I look in firebug the image tags are greyed out.

Anyone have any ideas?  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried writing the image as HTML to see if it shows up?

Answer (score 4):

If you can't display the image with

```
http://your_site.com/img/project_images/thumbs/wordherd-1_thumb.jpg
```

but you can display it with

```
http://your_site.com/app/webroot/img/project_images/thumbs/wordherd-1_thumb.jpg
```

Than the webserver url rewriting is missing or the rewrite rules are wrong.
If your cakephp app is in a subdirectory do not forget to use RewriteBase directiva.
If you do not use Apache check your webserver docs for correct rewriting.

Comment: My app isnt in a subdirectory, and the rest of my app is working fine, so shouldn't that mean that my .htacess and rewrite rules are good? Or are you talking about something different

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue

This URL really help me to fix my problem

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

I had installed cakephp in my subdirectory

CakePHP root directory (must be copied to your document; redirects everything to your CakePHP app):

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteBase /myfoldername/
      RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
      RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you load the image directly in browser? In firebug, check if the image has some styles that hide it (opacity:0 or display: none). Use a different browser, maybe there's a FF addon that prevents loading the images.

Comment: I can load the image using the full url /app/webroot/img/project_images/thumbs/ but if I try to link it like that in the view the result is a broken image :S  There is nothing in the browser causing the images to not show, I have tried various browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think @sipiatti has a ponit there. Try to do what he said.

Also, check for `chown`, and `chmod`

Answer (score 0):

i have met this problem too, but my problem was my file was named as .JPG not .jpg(upper case/lower case), so everything worked fine on my local machine under wamp and didn't on web server.
sometimes you must be just more careful.

Comment: this can happen quiet often if you develop in a windows machine and your server is running on a linux machine.